# Using boost::thread to start/stop logging data

Tags: multithreading

I'm currently trying to log real-time data by using boost::thread and a check box. When I check the box, the logging thread starts.  When I uncheck, the logging thread stops. The problem arises when I check/uncheck repeatedly and very fast (program crashes, some files aren't logged, etc.). How can I write a reliable thread-safe program where these problems don't occur when repeatedly and quickly checking/unchecking? I also don't want to use join() since this temporarily stops the data input coming from the main thread. Below is a code snippet:

```
//Main thread
 if(m_loggingCheckBox->isChecked())
  {

        ...

      if(m_ThreadLogData.InitializeReadThread(socketInfo))//opens the socket. 
         //If socket is opened and can be read, start thread.
            m_ThreadLogData.StartReadThread();
        else
            std::cout << "Did not initialize thread\n";
  }
  else if(!m_loggingCheckBox->isChecked())
  {

      m_ThreadLogData.StopReadThread();

  }

void ThreadLogData::StartReadThread()
{
    //std::cout << "Thread started." << std::endl;
    m_stopLogThread = false;
      m_threadSendData = boost::thread(&ThreadLogData::LogData,this);
}

void ThreadLogData::StopReadThread()
{
    m_stopLogThread = true;
    m_ReadDataSocket.close_socket();        // close the socket

    if(ofstreamLogFile.is_open())
    {
        ofstreamLogFile.flush();            //flush the log file before closing it.
        ofstreamLogFile.close();            // close the log file
    }
    m_threadSendData.interrupt();           // interrupt the thread
    //m_threadSendData.join();              // join the thread. Commented out since this temporarily stops data input.

}

//secondary thread
bool ThreadLogData::LogData()
{
      ... 

    while(!m_stopLogThread)
    {
        try {

                         //log the data to an output file
                         ...
                         boost::this_thread::interruption_point();

        } catch (boost::thread_interrupted& interruption) {
              std::cout << "ThreadLogData::LogData(): Caught Interruption thread." << std::endl;
              StopReadThread();
        } catch (...) {
              std::cout << "ThreadLogData::LogData(): Caught Something." << std::endl;
              StopReadThread();
        }

    } // end while()


}
```

Comment: Your code is riddled with race conditions - that is likely the center of your problem.  This compounded with a really vague question makes this hard to answer other than "fix your race conditions".  At every line, literally every line, ask yourself "what would happen if the checkbox changed between the last line and this one?"  For example, you check this "m_loggingCheckBox->isChecked()" multiple times - what happens if the value changes between calls?  Also look at using locks to make related changes logically atomic.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using boost::thread to start/stop logging data (2nd update)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22305470/using-boostthread-to-start-stop-logging-data-2nd-update)